# Check if specific record exists in one to many tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with one-to-many relation with such structure:

```
meeting              meeting_person
+--+------------+    +--+----------+-----------+---------+
|id|meeting_type|    |id|meeting_id|person_type|person_id|
+--+------------+    +--+----------+-----------+---------+
|1 |          1 |    |1 |         1|          1|     100 |
|2 |          2 |    |2 |         1|          1|     101 |
+--+------------+    |3 |         1|          2|     102 |
                     |4 |         2|          3|     103 |
                     +--+----------+-----------+---------+
```

What I want to do is check whether the specific record exists before inserting, and if so warn user about it.
The thing is I need to check whether a meeting with such `meeting_type` and `person_id` with `person_type` exists, and that for all persons.
For example, if with given data I wanted to insert meeting with meeting_type = 1 and such meeting_persons:

- person_type = 1 and person_id = 100
- person_type = 1 and person_id = 101
- person_type = 2 and person_id = 102
  then user should see warning.
  But if I wanted to insert meeting with meeting_type = 1 and such meeting_persons:
- person_type = 1 and person_id = 100
  then user should not see warning and records should be inserted.
  I just cannot think of way, how to check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know if a meeting with the meeting type and the persons in question already exists. So join and count:

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select m.id
  from meeting m
  join meeting_persion mp on mp.meeting_id = m.id
  where m.meeting_type = 1 
    and (mp.person_type, mp.person_id) in ((1,100),(1,101),(2,102))
  group by m.id
  having count(*) = 3
);
```

This query results in the number of matching meetings (0 or more).

If, however, you are only interested in meetings with exactly those persons, i.e. no additional persons, then you must move the criteria on persons from `WHERE` to `HAVING`:

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select m.id
  from meeting m
  join meeting_persion mp on mp.meeting_id = m.id
  where m.meeting_type = 1 
  group by m.id
  having count(case when (mp.person_type, mp.person_id) in ((1,100),(1,101),(2,102))
                    then 1 end) = 3
     and count(*) = 3
);
```

This query results in the number of matching meetings (0 or 1).

Comment: Those queries seems to suit my needs. Could you please explain "having count(*) = 3" (where this 3 is coming from)? Because I will need to build this query dynamically.

Comment: Three persons in this example. If you were looking for two or four or whatever, you'd have to adjust this number.

Answer (score 1):

As phrased, you need to use a trigger for this.  I might suggest changing the data structure to include `meeting_type` in `meeting_person`.  Yes, I know that violates normal form.  But if you had it, you could enforce your logic with a simple constraint:

```
alter table meeting_person add constraint unq_meetingperson_person_type
    unique (person_id, meeting_type);
```

How can you do this safely?  Use foreign key relationships:

```
alter table meeting add constraint unq_meeting_type_id
    unique (type, id);

alter table meeting_person add constraint fk_meetingperson_meetingtype_id
    foreign key (meeting_type, id) references meeting(meeting_type, id);
```

This does incur extra space for the additional (unnecessary) indexes.  It does require including one extra column in `meeting_type`.  But it does allow you to implement this logic without using triggers.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
WITH MEETING(ID, MEETING_TYPE) AS
 (SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL
  UNION SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL),
MEETING_PERSON(ID, MEETING_ID, PERSON_TYPE, PERSON_ID) AS
 (SELECT 1, 1, 1, 100 FROM DUAL
  UNION SELECT 2, 1, 1, 101 FROM DUAL
  UNION SELECT 3, 1, 2, 102 FROM DUAL
  UNION SELECT 4, 2, 3, 103 FROM DUAL)
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS show_warning FROM meeting, meeting_person 
WHERE meeting.id = meeting_person.meeting_id
AND meeting.meeting_type = 1 
AND (person_type, person_id) NOT IN ( (1,100),(1,101),(2,102) ); -- comment this and uncomment second line for second example to check
--AND (person_type, person_id) NOT IN ( (1,100) );
```

Comment: Because warning should be only if ALL conditions are the same, that is, all persons with that type matches. In first example I am trying to insert exact values, while in second example I am trying to insert only subset of existing values, which counts as different value and therefore should be inserted.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check if this suits your needs.